# MySQL query error with inner join and where

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

A bit on my layout (simplified):

```
users table
|userid|lastauth|
```

When a user logs in, lastauth is changed to the authid of the new login token.

```
auth table
|authid|token|
```

Given a token, I want to find out which userid it belongs to. I'm not sure if I'm using INNER JOINs right, but this SQL gives out an error:

```
SELECT users.userid 
FROM 'users' 
  INNER JOIN 'auth' on users.lastauth = auth.authid 
WHERE auth.token=1234567890abcdef
```

Comment: This is a simple syntax error. I vote to close as not constructive.

Comment: Ugg, I used the syntax from there http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ without realizing it's \` instead of '

Comment: @danihp: I don't think the lack of quotes around a character values is a simple syntax error. Seems like a misunderstanding on how literals (constants) have to be used in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use single quotes for object names. They are only for character literals (where you didn't use them):

```
SELECT users.userid 
FROM users 
  INNER JOIN auth on users.lastauth = auth.authid 
WHERE auth.token = '1234567890abcdef'
```

You probably mixing that up with those dreaded backticks in MySQL:

```
SELECT users.userid 
FROM `users`
  INNER JOIN `auth` on users.lastauth = auth.authid 
WHERE auth.token = '1234567890abcdef'
```

But as your table names are not reserved words, you don't need any type of quotes around your object names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.userid FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `auth` on users.lastauth = auth.authid 
WHERE auth.token='1234567890abcdef'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to:

```
SELECT users.userid FROM users INNER JOIN auth on users.lastauth = auth.authid WHERE auth.token='123abc';
```